# How a reference in C# is implemented internally?

Tags: c#, .net

Just wondering how a reference in C# is implemented internally?

alias? const pointer?

still need an elaborate answer on this.

thanks.

Comment: Why? The point is it's not relevant to C# programmer how this is implemented internally. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That's implementation-dependent. I'm afraid elaborate answers will be few and far between. Also, are you referring to reference types, `ref` arguments, or actual CLR references?

Comment: @Cody Gray, what business is it of yours? The guy is curious. If you don't have anything constructive to say, don't say anything.

Comment: @TomW: Uhh, I already explained what "business" it is of mine. It's implementation-dependent, it's not documented anywhere, and you're not supposed to rely on or assume any particular implementation. Generally, when people ask questions like this, they're trying to solve some particular problem. Since the answer to *this* question is going to be a non-starter, it would be much better to figure out what the *actual* problem he's trying to solve is, because then we could provide more appropriate solutions.

Comment: @TomW: I can't possibly understand how you interpreted my comment as "unconstructive". I've spent a hell of a lot more time here answering questions than you have. The number of answers that I've had accepted indicates that *most* people think my comments are constructive. Not sure what your problem is here.

Comment: Other people have answered the OP with useful reference material. What you did was assume that he doesn't know how to solve a practical problem, and tell him to stop asking stupid questions. Why would you presume to know the OP's reasoning in asking the question? Maybe he's interested in working on Mono. Maybe it's purely academic. In any case, you decided you were going to address the issue that **you** wanted to address, instead of approaching the question openly.

Comment: Not sure why you think that posting random links is any more useful than actually trying to solve a problem. But to each his own. Thank goodness comments don't have a downvote button. People sure do bristle when they don't get the answer they wanted. Apparently even if it's not *their* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current implementations, a reference is just a pointer.

To your program, there is no difference at all between a reference and a pointer, everything that is special about references is handled by the compiler and the garbage collector.

What's relevant to know, really, is that a reference doesn't take up more space than a pointer, and there is no extra step needed to use a reference. A reference is not a pointer to a pointer, or an identity that has to be looked up to get to the actual data.

The .NET memory management doesn't use reference counting, like some other frameworks, so there is no counter that has to be maintained when creating or removing references.

Comment: “[T]here is no difference at all between a reference and a pointer”. There is one big difference: a pointer can point to an invalid area of memory or to memory that wasn't allocated as the type of your pointer (which can be sometimes useful). With references, you can be sure that they always either point to an properly initialized instance of the type of your reference variable, or they are `null`.

Comment: @svick: You are mistaken. To the compiled program, there is no difference what so ever between the use of a reference and the use of a pointer. The difference that you are talking about is all in the compilation of the program, to the running program there is no difference.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood what you meant by “your program”. I assumed you mean the source code of the program, not the running JITed code.

Answer (score 1):

### References:

- [.NET Type Internals - From a Microsoft CLR Perspective](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/net_type_internals.aspx)
- [Heap, Stack, Reference Types and Value Types in .NET](http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/2008/01/31/Heap+Stack+Reference+Types+And+Value+Types+In+NET.aspx)
- [Exploring the CLR (Types)](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=99977&seqNum=3)